# Correct handling of negative chapter numbers

Tags: sectioning

I have a book that starts with Chapter -1. I can almost make this work by including

```
\setcounter{chapter}{-2}
```

in the preamble, except that in Chapter -1, the minus sign is displayed as a hyphen rather than a minus sign, because it isn't in math mode. If I add the commands

```
\let\chapnum\thechapter
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{$\chapnum$}
```

then this introduces new problems, because in many instances the chapter number is not displayed in bold (for example, in theorem numbering).

What I'd like to do is to force the minus sign to be a `\textminus` or some similar symbol, so that it's in text mode. How do I do that?

Thank you!

Comment: You could also try adding `\boldmath` to your header formatting, so math-mide symbols display as bold.

Comment: Once in a while people really ask surprising questions. This is one of them. You need to implement this thoroughly. The first footnote needs to be negative as well. Maybe someone can program a macro that calculates the starting point in a way, that footnote 1 is the first footnote in chapter 1. Same for page numbers! The title page is minus X, so that the first page of chapter 1 is one. And when you are at it: why not have as many negative chapters as positive ones! Your whole work in sum were zero. I have a title: »wiffing vacuum»

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Something like this perhaps:

```
\documentclass{book}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\renewcommand{\thechapter}
  {
    \int_compare:nNnT{\value{chapter}}<{0}{\textminus}
    \int_abs:n{\value{chapter}}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\setcounter{chapter}{-2}
\begin{document}
 \chapter{chapter}\label{chap}
 \section{section}
 \ref{chap}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The minus sign looks too long to me.

Comment: @graffe the OP asked for `\textminus`, but you can use whatever you want instead.

Answer (score 8):

[Ulrike's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/663903) is the right way to go as it avoids too much overhead. But as a demonstration, we could also do this with `siunitx` without needing a conditional:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\renewcommand\thechapter{\num[mode = text,
  reset-text-family = false, reset-text-series  = false,
  reset-text-shape = false, evaluate-expression]{\value{chapter}}}
\setcounter{chapter}{-2}
\begin{document}
 \chapter{chapter}\label{chap}
 \section{section}
 \ref{chap}
\end{document}
```